# I am looking at a linear regression that cannot have points below its curve?

Tags: numpy, linear-regression

[image]

Basically, as shown in this image, i want to know if there is a linear regression model that allows to have all the points above its curve while still doing a linear regression. In this image, all the points with the lowest time are interesting as the excess time is only due to noise.

hence, is there a linear regression model that allows to have all the points above (or below) its curve while still doing a proper linear regression ?

#########################

here is an illustration of what i wish to obtain without using witchcratftry.
[image]

Comment: I think you can apply any method for robust regression. For example RANSAC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) can be a good choice.

Comment: Second vote for 'robust' regression. For another example, try [`sklearn.linear_model.HuberRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.HuberRegressor.html).

Comment: i have tried the HuberRegressor and while the line did in fact get lowered it was not by a significant amount, at least not significant enough to get a satisfactory result.

Comment: I have also tried RANSAC and obtained similarly the same results.

Comment: what could be ideal is if there was a way to weight the loses depending on whether the points are above or below the curve, if you'd know a way to do that, it would be ideal.

Comment: i did manage to get what i wanted but this was done using some "magic", by weighting the points below the first obtained curve more than those above and then re-running the regression. but i don't find this solution very elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Can I do a linear regression with the constraint that all points are above the curve ?

I don't think there is such a thing in scikit-learn but you can just minimize the square distance of your function from the points, subject to the constraint, using scipy's minimize.

First I generate an example

```
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.linspace(0,250,100)
y = 0.5*x+np.abs(np.random.normal(0,10,x.shape))
y[np.random.randint(0,y.shape[0],3)] += 100
```

I do your constrained least squares

```
def con(a):
    return np.min(y-(a[0]*x+a[1]))

cons=({'type': 'ineq','fun': con})

def f(a):
    return np.linalg.norm(y-(a[0]*x+a[1]))

x0 = [0.1,-1]

res = minimize(f, x0, constraints=cons)
```

And plot the result

```
a,b = res.x
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,a*x+b)
```

[image: constrained least squares]

Comment: you forgot the parenthesis for con and f, I'd like to comment it but can't since I'd need to input more than 6 character and don't really need to. BTW thanks for the answer that was what i was looking for all along

Comment: y-a[0]*x+a[1] -> y-(a[0]*x+a[1])